# Is a question on setting up a CTAN mirror on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to setup a CTAN mirror but didn't get far after reading https://www.ctan.org/mirrors/register/ . I'd like to post something like *Idiots guide to setting up a CTAN mirror* as a question on tex.stackexchange.com

An answer to my question would probably revolve around current web server practices best suited for such a mirror, and so potentially be off-topic. But since the main audience would be LaTeX users, this seems a more natural fit. The question would be answerable: I would know upon successfully setting up such a mirror that the answer given was right.

Comment: From hosting about 10 different accessible, if not strictly public, mirrors at my workplace, there's not much to setting up a CTAN mirror that's any different than the other mirrors. If you have a Unix-like operating system with rsync, you can get the upstream CTAN files mirrored to a local directory. If you can set up a web server, you can point it at that local directory to serve those files. It's basically a sysadmin-type question, but that audience is already relatively well-served by the existing document.

Comment: Did you see [Establishing a new LaTeX repository in the university](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119316/14500)?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your true meta question: Yes, such questions are on-topic. The fact that they revolve around *operating* TeX rather than *using* it does not disqualify them. What is not on-topic are trivial questions (even in this area, there are trivial questions) and questions irrelevant to the TeX side of the problem (like asking how to install/setup an Apache server or a cron job).

There are some insights in [Establishing a new LaTeX repository in the university](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119316/establishing-a-new-latex-repository-in-the-university) (as pointed out by Paul Gaborit), make sure your question is significantly different.

Comment: Why would questions be off-topic if they are trivial? That notion doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @clemens "Trivial" may be an unfortunate word here. I mean that their answer is very easy to find. Any ideas how to describe it better?

Comment: I would argue that triviality is no criterion for being on-topic or not. I'd consider the question “How to make text bold?” on-topic even if the solution (use `\textbf{text}`) is trivial

Comment: I would, however, not consider things like "how to upload a package to CTAN" when the answer is simply at https://ctan.org/help

Comment: Then we disagree at this point :)